# SQL: calculating % using the results of two queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know how to query my database to find how many users I had in the last period, and I know how to query it to find how many people purchased in the last period. Now, I'd love to combine the two to find out what % of users purchased in the last period (conversion rate).

Here is my attempt, but it didn't seem to work :/ any help greatly appreciated! (using PostgreSQL)

```
with user_count as
(select count(distinct user_id) from log),
buyer_count as (select count (distinct user_id) from log where event_type = 'Purchase')
select buyer_count / user_count * 100 as 'conversion_rate' from log
where country = 'XX' and date = 'XX'
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select (count(distinct case when event_type = 'Purchase' then user_id end) * 100.0 /
        nullif(count(distinct user_id), 0)
      ) as conversion_rate
from log l
where country = 'XX' and date = 'XX'
```

Comment: Now trying to reverse engineer how you did it :D